# Javascript code in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have created a script to random the size but i am unable to figure about how can i use it with HTML or Iframe code to randomize it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var banner1 = ["728", "90"];
    var banner2 = ["336", "280"];
    var banner3 = ["300", "250"];

    var allbanner = [banner1, banner2, banner3];

    var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];

</script>
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div style="height:"banner[0]"px;width:"banner[1]"px;color:blue;background-color:blue;"></div>

 <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="banner[0]" height="banner[1]"></iframe>
```

This is correct format, I know it wrong, can anyone please tell me how can i use Javascript string in HTML Attribute.

Thanks you .

Comment: You can't do it directly like that unless you're using some kind of templating engine. Alternatively you can change element attributes from JS.

Comment: Can you please tell me how it possible, I am really week in coding. Or it possible to have iframe with javascript so it accept javascript string.

Comment: If you're weak in coding, start running through some tutorials. JQuery might be a sensible start if you want to do a lot of DOM updates from JS.

Answer (score 4):

You can't mix and match HTML and JavaScript like you're attempting to do. You must modify the DOM from the script.

```
var banner1 = ["728", "90"];
var banner2 = ["336", "280"];
var banner3 = ["300", "250"];

var allbanner = [banner1, banner2, banner3];

var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

myDiv.style.height = banner[0] + 'px';
myDiv.style.width = banner[1] + 'px';

myIframe.style.height = banner[0] + 'px';
myIframe.style.width = banner[1] + 'px';
```

Assuming your HTML is something like:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="color:blue;background-color:blue;"></div>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="www.othersite.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, How can i do it with iframe. I understanding.

Comment: @MauryaAshish do what with an iframe? Modify the attributes of the iframe? In that case the process is exactly the same. If you need help with DOM manipulation in JavaScript I'd look for a beginner's tutorial.